# Export time series mesh data to grid

Tags: qgis, time-series, mesh

I have a grib file containing temperature and precipitation, monthly, from 1989 to 2019 for a specific region (extracted from ERA5-Land).

I imported it in QGIS as a mesh layer.

I need to locate those data on a grid I already made (to add the id of my grid cells to each value of the mesh, and then aggregate temperature and precipitation at the grid scale).

I have never used time series spatial data, so my approach could be wrong.

First, I used the mesh function "export time series values from points of a mesh dataset", and as "points for data export" I put my grid shapefile.
The CSV file I got had the right time period, but each value was NaN, the identifier was 0 for each observation, and  both  x and y coordinates were 0.

So I tried using the function "export mesh on grid", but I got temperature and precipitation averaged over the whole period while I would like to keep each observation in time.

What is the best way to do this?

Edit : is there a way while using "export mesh on grid", to create one variable for each time-period/variable combination ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue, I divided the problem.

First, I used Python to get a traditional dataframe.
More details here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67963199/xarray-from-grib-file-to-dataset/67995661#67995661

From here, I just kept one observations for each location.
Then, I imported this file back to qgis as data point and was able to do the intersection with my grid.

Then, in another statistical software I just merge those IDs obtained with the intersection with the rest of the data containing the variables for each year.